# SQL - Where clause with case statement and wildcards

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I'm working in Oracle's APEX environment, trying to return all values in one case and specific values in another case. If you aren't familiar with APEX, it uses low-code to produce a front-end page that is data driven; this case uses a dropdown to select from a list, and I'm comparing that list selection to values pulled from my database.

This creates the dropdown list (requires 2 columns - a display column [name], and a return column [id]):

```
select distinct 'All users' as name,
 '99999' as id
from real_table
union
select distinct name,
 id
from real_table
```

That input is stored in a variable we'll call :LIST_INPUT. I want to select all values from another_table when 'All users' is selected, and only those associated with the particular user when their name/id is selected. Below is the code I have to try and achieve that, but no dice.

```
select name,
 id,
 other_col1,
 other_col2
from another_table
where case
  when :LIST_INPUT like '99999' then '%'
  else :LIST_INPUT
 end like id
```

This works fine when a real user id is selected, but returns nothing when the 'All users' value is selected. My logic here is that I'm asking it to compare a wildcard to the ID field, so it should return everything, but instead it returns nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably case statement is not necesasary, look:

```sql
select name,
       id,
       other_col1,
       other_col2
  from another_table
 where id = :LIST_INPUT
    OR :LIST_INPUT like '99999' -- You can use any other condition here
```

Comment: Also works! I wish I had access to my execution plan to see which was more efficient, but I suspect this is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your `LIKE` operator has the operands in the wrong order. Shouldn't it be?

```
select name,
 id,
 other_col1,
 other_col2
from another_table
where id like case
  when :LIST_INPUT like '99999' then '%'
  else :LIST_INPUT
  end
```

Comment: Well, that did it. Thank you!

In other where/case clauses I've written (in the same query, no less), I put the comparison at the end and it appears to work just fine (I have to exclude a particular ID, so `where case when id = '75' then 1 else 0 end = 1`), but maybe it's not doing what I thought!